# What is the password for jenkins user during first installation?

Tags: passwords, jenkins, continuous-integration, credentials, slave

I want to put one Jenkins server (Ubuntu 12.04) to slave mode. But master machine must know a password for "jenkins" user on a slave machine. How do I specify the password when it has been auto-created during Jenkins installation?

Comment: When installing Jenkins (or generally any other server package) it just adds a user account -- there is no password set. But you don't need to install the Jenkins package on slaves anyway. You can create a `jenkins` (or any other) user account on the slave, then when adding a new slave via the master web UI, enter those credentials.