# What is the default jenkins user password

Tags: jenkins

I have installed Jenkins and during installation an user named `jenkins` has been created. I can see from the documentation:

```
[The 'jenkins' user is created to run this service.][1]
```

What is the default password for this jenkins user?

I have checked the SO question - [What is the password for jenkins user during first installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372992/what-is-the-password-for-jenkins-user-during-first-installation) which does not provide this answer.

Another question is - if I change the jenkins user password using Linux command `passwd jenkins` and restart Jenkins server will Jenkins server start? Or there is some other way of changing the Jenkins user password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are now password for system users or they are unknown totaly. These users are usually used by calling su -c "command" username or setting UID or GID for process. These users are exposed for security meaning only (for setting appropriate access mode for files and directories) and nothing more. There is no need to change the password and use this user.